# Google sheets - Update date cells based on criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to update dates in a sheet once a week.

I would like to manually run a script to do this.

Each date in column "C" will increase by a number of days in column "D" in same row.
Only dates prior to a date in specific cell (F2 in example) will be updated.

See this sheet as an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11f6G5_vNK5Z8UR2A_MUUXpL8awC2mJ8ozpnznWQ_anM/edit?usp=sharing

| Column C - Service Date | Column D - No. of days to advance |
| --- | --- |
| 12/3/2021 | 7 |
| 12/3/2021 | 14 |
| 12/10/2021 | 7 |
| 12/10/2021 | 7 |
| 12/17/2021 | 28 |

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be great!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, the cells "C2" and "D2" are `12/3/2021` and `7`, respectively. And, the cell "F2" is `12/4/2021`. So I cannot understand the logic of your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I likely have not explained very well. The logic of the script would be: IF C2 is less than F2, increase C2 by number of days in D2. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, where do you want to put the values?

Comment: the new values would replace/overwrite the old values in column C

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how do you want to do for the cells "C3:C"? You want to compare all values of "C3:C" with the cell "F2"?

Comment: Hi. Yes all values C2:C would be compared with F2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function updateDates() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const dt = new Date(sh.getRange('F2').getValue());
  const dthv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const oA = [];
  vs.forEach(r => {
    let d = new Date(r[2]);
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf();
    if(dv < dthv) {
      oA.push([new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate() + r[3])]);
    } else {
      oA.push([r[2]]);
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(2,3,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Sheet 0 Before:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 11/10/2021 | 5 |  | 11/15/2021 |
|  |  | 11/11/2021 | 6 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/12/2021 | 7 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/13/2021 | 8 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/14/2021 | 9 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/15/2021 | 10 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/16/2021 | 11 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/17/2021 | 12 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/18/2021 | 13 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/19/2021 | 14 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/20/2021 | 15 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/21/2021 | 16 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/22/2021 | 17 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/23/2021 | 18 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/24/2021 | 19 |  |  |

Sheet0 After:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 11/15/2021 | 5 |  | 11/15/2021 |
|  |  | 11/17/2021 | 6 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/19/2021 | 7 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/21/2021 | 8 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/23/2021 | 9 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/15/2021 | 10 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/16/2021 | 11 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/17/2021 | 12 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/18/2021 | 13 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/19/2021 | 14 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/20/2021 | 15 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/21/2021 | 16 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/22/2021 | 17 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/23/2021 | 18 |  |  |
|  |  | 11/24/2021 | 19 |  |  |